# How to use Scaled function

Tags: plotting

I'm a  beginner and I am really confused with the `Scaled` function:

What does 0.1, 0.2 mean?

Also, if I want to draw a 3d graph of $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$, with 1, 2, 3, 5 marked on the x, y coordinate, what syntax should I use?

This is my code:

```
Show[{Plot3D[(x*y^2)/(x^2 + y^4), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {-1, 0.6}], 
  Graphics3D[{Text["x", Scaled[{-.05, .5, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["y", Scaled[{.5, -.05, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["z", Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

It looks like the graph doesn't match when x,y is near 0, the limit should be 0.5. So I think I need to adjust the scaling.

Another problem is if x=0.01, y=0.1, the function's value should be 0.5, but (0.01,0.1,0.5) is not on the graph, is it still a problem about the scaling?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Something went wrong with your link; no image is showing. Please note also that it would be best for you to post your code in a copy / paste ready format, in addition to any images.

Comment: I find this post confusing. Is the question about getting the ticks right or about scaling the x, y, and z axis labels.

Comment: The function does not have a unique limit at {0,0}. Mathematica fails to make a good plot because of this discontinuity. If you reduce the plot range to a much smaller region, you will find that the requested 0.5 value is somewhere there, but there will always be some nasty visual artifact near the origin.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the ticks you appear to be requesting.

```
Show[
  {Plot3D[(x*y^2)/(x^2 + y^4), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
     BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1},
     Mesh -> 5,
     Ticks -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5], Automatic},
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold, 12]],
   Graphics3D[
     {Text[Style["x", Bold, 12], Scaled[{1.1, .5, .5}]],
      Text[Style["y", Bold, 12], Scaled[{.5, 1.1, .5}]],
      Text[Style["z", Bold, 12], Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}]},
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: plot]

About the scaling I can't figure out what you are asking. I will note that

```
Limit[(x*y^2)/(x^2 + y^4), x -> 0]
```

> `0`

not `.5` as you seem to think.

#### Update

In a 3D plot the usual way to draw attention to a point is place a small sphere on the surface at the indicated xy-coordinates. This is also usually done with plots made with an undistorted Euclidean metric (`BoxRatios -> Automatic`) to keep the sphere to being distorted.

It is very hard to see the sphere unless it has a diameter of at least 1% of the maximum span of plot. This means the granularity of the visual point space is rather coarse.

Here is what adding such a sphere to your surface looks in an undistorted version.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x*y^2)/(x^2 + y^4)

Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    PlotPoints -> 30,
    Ticks -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5], Automatic}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold, 12]],
  Graphics3D[
   {{Red, Sphere[{2., 3., f[2., 3.]}, Scaled[.0075]]},
    Text[Style["x", Bold, 12], Scaled[{1.1, .5, .5}]], 
    Text[Style["y", Bold, 12], Scaled[{.5, 1.1, .5}]], 
    Text[Style["z", Bold, 12], Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}],
  BoxRatios -> Automatic,
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: pt-plot]

I placed the point at `{2, 3}` so it us out in the open and easily seen. Note that I also converted the expression you are plotting into a function so the centers of any spheres you would wish to place on the surface can be readily calculated.

#### Update 2

The point `{.01, .1, .5}` is indeed on the surface. It is in a region where the surface is ill-behaved, so *Mathematica* has a hard time drawing there. In fact, when the domain is `{x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}` *Mathematica* can't show what the region really looks like. To see that part of surface in detail, the domain must be greatly restricted. Even then *Mathematica* has to work hard.

Here a plot that shows the section you are interested in sufficient detail:

```
Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    PlotPoints -> 200], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{.01, .1, f[.01, .1]}, Scaled[.0075]]}], 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic,
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: cusp-plot]

Note how the red dot is sitting on a razor sharp ridge, just a bit off from a what appears to be  a deep plunge to zero. However, the plunge is an artifact of the plotting process. The ridge actually runs across the `x = 0` line, but the inflection becomes so sharp, *Mathematica* can't show it.

The topography of the region around `{.01, .1}` makes it hard to plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also want to spot a point on the graph for example when x=0.01, y=0.1, and I want to mark the point in red on the graph, what's the syntax for it

Comment: @whoisit. At the scale of this plot, a point at `{.01, .1}` can't be distinguished from a point at `{0, 0}`.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I still don't get it that if I set x=0.01, y=0.1, the function's value is 0.5, but (0.01,0.1,0.5) is not on the graph? I have added new pictures in my original post, It is a red dot that repesents (0.01,0.1,0.5), it's obvious not on the graph

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot3D[x y^2/(x^2 + y^4), {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
       Ticks -> {Range@5,Range@5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also want to spot a point on the graph for example when x=0.01, y=0.1, and I want to mark the point in red on the graph, what's the syntax for it

Comment: @whoisit **Strongly** related to your comment: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1808/193

Comment: Nice link, particularly the third comment.